# Distribute Virtual machine supporting multi platform of visualization

Tags: virtualization, ovf, multi-platform

I would like to create a virtual machine for distribution,
My question is - how can I support all the major virtualization platforms?
(VmWare, VirtualBox & HyperV)

Is there an easy way to generate a virtual machine file (like ovf) for all of those platform without creating the machine in each of those?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Of course tooling exists to create virtual machine appliances for multiple hypervisors.

Use as an example your favorite open source project that releases multiple VM appliances. Look up their build system scripts, or ask around how they work.  Likely either home grown scripts or based on something like [Packer](https://www.packer.io/intro/use-cases.html).

For ease of use you want to create multiple images. Hyper-V cannot easily consume OVA archives with VMDK disks, nor does VMware consume VHDX disks. Asking users to convert a disk image with a V2V procedure may be a bit much, although documenting that process will be appreciated.